# If ((decnumber - 28) > 0) correct? My dec to binary maker is returning ALL 00000000

Tags: c

```
if ((decnumber - 128) > 0)
   {
     bin[7] = 1;
     decnumber = decnumber - 128;
   }
```

Im tring to make a program that converts dec to binary and prints it on the screen
Is this the problem? Its returning nothing but 0000000

heres my loop front printing

int
main ()
{

```
while (p > 0)
  {
    int digit = bin[p];
    printf ("%d", digit);
    p = p - 1;
  }
```

i cant seem to paste the whole code anyway, stackoverflow says its TOO MUCH lol

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is not very clear what you are asking. Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows complete code. May I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you trying to take a number like `5` and output "00000101" ?

Comment: you create a [mcve]/[sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) instead of posting everything you wrote (which no one would read anyway). Also learn [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)